# Remove slashes from large paragraph

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripslashes

In iOS app, I send data through JSON to iPhone device.
My paragraph is large text containing multiple newline. Similarly to [stripslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php), how can I remove slash along with them in iOS Objective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you have to do it manually. E.g.:

```
NSString *str = @"Test string with some \' and some \" \'\"";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\'" withString:@"'"];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"\""];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Comment: it does not work on my string coming from the server, checking again

Comment: Will fail for `@"\\''"`, and the example is poorly written, as slashes need to be escaped in an NSString literal.

Answer (score 0):

To remove simple `\` like in `O\'Reilly` use:

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
```

Comment: it's old for you but will be probably new for someone else ;)

Comment: Will fail for `@"\\\\'"`. Double backslashes (``\\``) should be made into a single backslash (``\``).

Answer (score 0):

#### general stripslashes (except for control characters)

If the scope is un-quoting all backslash-quoted characters like [`stripslashes`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) PHP function *without magic_quotes_sybase*, then a regular expression replacement will do, except for control characters like NUL (`\0`):

```
NSString *str = @"\\\\ \\' \\\" \\r\\s\\t\\u";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\(.)" withString:@"$1" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
```

#### reverse addslashes

If the scope is limited to reverse the [`addslashes`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) PHP function, then only 4 characters need to be unescaped/unquoted: NUL, double quote, single quote and backslash.

```
NSString *str = @"\\\\ \\' \\\" \\\0";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\0" withString:@"\0"];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"\""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\'" withString:@"\'"];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"];
```

#### unquote JSON

You shouldn't use [`addslashes`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) or [`stripslashes`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) for JSON content at all. Escaping rules for JSON are described in https://json.org/:
[image]

For instance, `stripslashes` will not support `\u` + *4 hexadecimal digits*.

So if the scope is un-quoting JSON format (NOT `stripslashes`-like), then use a JSON parser:

```
NSString *str = @"\\\" \\\\ \\u26C4";
str = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", str] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one

```
  NSString *valorTextField = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello \ world"];
  NSString *replaced = [valorTextField stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\" withString:@""];
 NSLog(@"%@", replaced);
```

Comment: Doesn't even build as slashes need to be escaped in an NSString literal. Also, would be a duplicate answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/19079469/1033581 and would fail for `@"\\\\'"`, as double backslashes (``\\``) should be made into a single backslash (``\``).